# Is there difference in memory between: Storing datas in an Array as NSDictionary OR as seperate model objects?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Assume I have an array **employees1**:

```
[
{"id":"1", "name":"Bill"},
{"id":"2", "name":"Jhon"},
{"id":"3", "name":"Almas"},
]
```

OR an Array **employees2** with `Employee` objects:

```
@interface Employee : NSObject {
    NSNumber *employeeID;
    NSString *name;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *employeeID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
```

The second case is more Object Oriented which is easy to use in large projects.
If I have a lot of employees, will **employee2** array allocate more (2x, 3x ...) memory than **employee1**? How much they differ?

Comment: The separate object solution (#2) is better by miles and screw the memory (which I cannot see as being any different anyway).

Comment: @trojanfoe I've edited my question) it is Employee object in an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, likely lower memory footprint with the object-oriented model because you aren't requiring the overhead of `NSDictionary` instances.

However, you can (as I just did) write a trivial test case and run it on Instruments to prove it to yourself.  In this case, I constructed such a test with your model, creating 10K objects and showed that your overall memory footprint was ~23% lower using custom objects.

Always better to test, although honestly the object-oriented model is so much clearer that in the long run, a small difference in memory footprint even if it were a negative difference may be better.

To editorialize: I see numerous questions here and elsewhere that pertain to the construction of the entire model layer of the application on `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`.  I can't imagine what a headache it would be to maintain that code in perpetuity.  So much clearer using object-orientation.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be worrying about these things before it's actually a problem. And if memory **is** a problem, you should solve it by not always having all employees in memory at once, i.e. persisting data to disk, and fetching it when needed. 
[Here's a guide on memory management and how to prevent memory-related problems](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: I understand what u mean. Actually I just wanna know, if the same  array with NSDictionary vs objects will differ in memory. Namely, which Obj-c structure is more heavy...?